# Paypal Error Message 3514

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

On my website there are 2 system of payment. 
One Time Purchase & Monthly Subscription (recurring).

Both Process are working with my sandbox account successfully on local server.

But when trying to check on live server with actual paypal account, Monthly package is working perfect, 
BUT "one time purchase" getting this Following error :

Paypal Error Message 3514
We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while 
making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before reseeding a payment.
For some browsers, this problem can be resolved by clearing or deleting cookies.

Message 3514

User can redirecting to paypal screen but on that screen this error occurred. 
Please, give me exact solution.
For monthly subscription button is created from paypal account and that code is used.

[image]